# Why does an object as a map value need to have an empty/default constructor when using [] in C++?

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I don't really understand why a class needs to have a default constructor when it is being used as a map value.

If you don't have a default constructor, it will give you an error saying: **In template: no matching constructor for initialization**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class MyClass
{
  public:
     MyClass(int test) {};
     MyClass() {};

};

int main() {
    std::map<int, MyClass> myMap;
    myMap[1] = MyClass(42);
}
```

This code will give me no error since I have a default constructor. Can someone help me understand why I need a default constructor. Thanks.

Comment: Because `operator[]` will create an object if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Replace `myMap[1] = MyClass(42);` with `myMap.emplace(1, 42);`, then you won't need the default constructor in MyClass.

Comment: @Eljay -- those do two different things when there is already an element with a matching key. The first replaces the mapped value and the second leaves the original value in place.

Comment: @PeteBecker • very true.  In the OP's code, there is not already an element with a matching key.  For a more general solution, the code would have to check for the key in the map, then either update or emplace accordingly.  (In my SQL days, we'd call that an `UPSERT` stored procedure.)

Comment: @Eljay `myMap.insert_or_assign(1, 42);` is the correct equivalent